# What code runs when I type "sudo service nginx start"

Tags: command-line, services, nginx

I am having this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939072/add-nginx-as-a-ubuntu-service-stop-and-reload-doesnt-work

I am trying to understand if my code to start *nginx* is point to the same *PID* file as my `nginx.conf` file.

How do I know what code runs when I type `sudo service nginx start` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sudo` part just starts the rest with `root` priviliges.

The manual pages for service say that

```
service SCRIPT COMMAND
```

executes a System V init script located in `/etc/init.d/SCRIPT` or, in case of the system using Upstart, an upstart job in `/etc/init`.

If you have both:

> The existence of an upstart job of the same name as a script in /etc/init.d
>   will cause the upstart job to take precedence over the  init.d  script.

The handling of COMMAND depends on whether an init script or an upstart job is invoked.

Comment: AFAIK `system` doesn't know anything about upstart, and diverting to upstart is done via a sourced script in the init script. Modern `system` is `systemd` aware though.

Comment: @jordanm why the reference to `system` the OP asks about `service` AFAIK and at least on my Ubuntu system it tries system V or upstart scripts.

Comment: sorry, I meant service. It tries upstart because of `init_is_upstart()` in `/lib/lsb/init-functions`.

Comment: @jordanm I was not aware of how upstart hooks into the service, just referring to what the man page for `service` describes (on Ubuntu 12.04).